# Access typescript functions into angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.8

I have created a typescript module and generating javascript file after compiling it, further I am using that javascript file into angular folder in index.html. my javascript file is getting loaded. but, I am not able to access the functionality of javascript file inside any angular controller or service ?

How can I access them ? Let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Edit:

How can I access 3rd party javascript library(compiled from typescript), and its functionality from angular class.

Edit:

My code is as below

```
export class DynamicClass {

    loadB1Data() {

    }

    getAccess() {

    }

}
let Dynamic = new DynamicClass();
```

and Its generating below js file after compile Dynamic.js

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var DynamicClass = (function () {
        function DynamicClass() {
        }
        DynamicClass.prototype.loadB1Data = function () {
        };
        DynamicClass.prototype.getAccess = function () {
        };
        return DynamicClass;
    }());
    exports.DynamicClass = DynamicClass;
    let;
    var Dynamic = (function () {
        function Dynamic() {
        }
        return Dynamic;
    }());
    new DynamicClass();
});
```

I created typed-definitions file dynamic.d.ts

```
interface Dynamic {
    loadB1Data(): any;
    getAccess(): any;
}

declare module DynamicLoad {
export let Dynamic:Dynamic
}
```

Now, I want to access loadB1Data and getAccess from external angularjs project. How is it possible ? I am using angular 1.5.6 version.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but, I am not able to access the functionality of javascript file inside any angular controller or service

You are most likely running into *undeclared variable errors*. You need to declare them.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: do I need to create fileName.d.ts, and it will contain method signature, and will add in my angular JS project ?

Comment: I have updated my question